# How to rescan missing multipathd paths?

Tags: linux, storage, multipath

I have multipath configured in ubuntu 14 server but strangely the number of path available for each device is different where the 5TB disk have 4 path and 4TB have 3 path. I have reloaded the multipath service and run rescan-scsi-bus but the output is same but havent rebooted server yet

```
# multipath -ll
3611112ac0000000000000002018 dm-9 zdata,VV              
size=5.0T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=130 status=active
  |- 4:0:3:52 sdaa 65:160 active ready running
  |- 4:0:4:52 sdad 65:208 active ready running
  |- 6:0:3:52 sdag 66:0   active ready running
  `- 6:0:4:52 sdaj 66:48  active ready running

378192dab0000000000000002018 dm-6 zdata,VV              
size=4.0T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=130 status=active
  |- 4:0:4:50 sdh  8:112  active ready running
  |- 6:0:3:50 sdn  8:208  active ready running
  `- 6:0:4:50 sdt  65:48  active ready running

# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 maj  6 11:37 378192dab0000000000000002018 -> ../dm-1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,2 maj  9 14:07 3611112ac0000000000000002018
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   3 maj  9 14:07 
crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 maj  6 11:35 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 maj  9 14:07 serv1--vg-data -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 jun 13 14:19 serv1--vg-backup1 -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        8 jun 13 14:32 serv1--vg-web -> ../dm-12
```

Any idea where to look now ?